problems connecting to the ec2 instance deployed in the custom vpc
I have basic understanding of aws but no work experience and now I'm learning terraform from youtube. I was trying a code from the tutorial, the code works, I've mostly copied the code from Terraform docs. But I cant access my ec2 instance from the public IP or through SSH.
here's my code:
resource "aws_vpc" "prod-vpc" {
     cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

     tags = {
       Name = "Production"
     }
}



resource "aws_internet_gateway" "prod-gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "prod-gateway"
  }
}


 resource "aws_route_table" "prod-routetable" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.prod-gateway.id
  }

  route {
    ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.prod-gateway.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "prod"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "prod-subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "prod-subnet"
  } 
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt-1" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.prod-subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.prod-routetable.id
}


resource "aws_security_group" "allow_web" {
  name        = "allow_Web"
  description = "Allow web inbound traffic and all outbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_web"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allow_web_ipv4" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_web.id
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  from_port         = 80
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  to_port           = 80
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allow_web_ipv6" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_web.id
  cidr_ipv6         = "::/0"
  from_port         = 443
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  to_port           = 443
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allow_ssh" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_web.id
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  from_port         = 22
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  to_port           = 22
}


resource "aws_vpc_security_group_egress_rule" "allow_all_traffic_ipv4" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_web.id
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  ip_protocol       = "-1" # semantically equivalent to all ports
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_egress_rule" "allow_all_traffic_ipv6" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_web.id
  cidr_ipv6         = "::/0"
  ip_protocol       = "-1" # semantically equivalent to all ports
}


resource "aws_network_interface" "server-nic" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.prod-subnet.id
  private_ips     = ["10.0.1.50"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_web.id]

    attachment {
    instance     = aws_instance.my-server.id
    device_index = 1
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "my-server" {
  ami = "ami-04e5276ebb8451442"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  key_name = "my-key"

  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo apt update -y
    sudo apt install apache2 -y
    sudo systemctl start apache2
    sudo systemctl enable apache2
  EOF
}

I tried asking chatGPT for the solution, it reviewed the terraform code and said the configurations were fine. security groups allows all traffic on port 22,80 and 443. NACL also allows all traffic 100: o.o.o.o/o allow. I don't understand where's the problem, it mostly in networking but in don't know where.

Do you see the public IP assigned to the EC2 instance in the AWS console?

Yes. there wasn't one, then I added "map_public_ip_on_launch = true" line. but when I click on the public IP it shows "This site can't be reached". In putty it show"Network error".

Well, when you click in the console, I suspect it is using HTTPS, so you could try with http://<ip.add.re.ss> which is the public IP. Which command are you using in Putty?

Hey,  I followed the tutorial again and found my mistake, I was typing in the wrong user name in putty. the tutorial used ubuntu but I used Amazon linux. lol
Thanks anyway.
